# Facebook Like button causing error in Firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox, button, facebook-like

I'm trying to use the Facebook 'Like' button on my site, but I cannot get it to work properly in Firefox. Using Firebug I can see that I am getting the error 'FB.provide is not a function', but I have no idea how to fix this.

It also appears that when I refresh the page in IE there is only about a 50/50 chance of the 'Like' button loading without causing an error.

Any help here would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check in the FF error console??? Please post your code...

Comment: Hay Karthink - The error I get in the console is 'FB.provide is not a function', and the code that I use is the exact code that is generated by the FB code cenerator. Thanks.

Comment: Read this thread, you'll have your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084091/facebook-share-comments-dont-work-like-they-should

Comment: Star - thanks for that. I had a generic 'Share of Facebook' link for all pages on my site, and this 'Like' button only showed up on a few. Thanks.

Comment: I've never used FB like button but when I checked this link it explains the issue with FF version 6 of FB `like`button:http://wordpress.org/support/topic/facebook-like-button-not-showing-up-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you add the Facebook script twice on the site (search for "all.js").

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4084335/2440